# How to fix WSL network was not found

Tags: networking, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2, windows-networking

ITNOA

#### Windows Version

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1702]

#### WSL Version

WSL version: 1.2.5.0

#### Are you using WSL 1 or WSL 2?

- [X] WSL 2
- [ ] WSL 1

#### Kernel Version

*No response*

#### Distro Version

Ubuntu 22.04

#### Other Software

*No response*

#### Repro Steps

After I run wsl, I see below error

```
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/CreateVm/ConfigureNetworking/0x803b0001
The network was not found.
```

#### Expected Behavior

Run WSL Correctly

#### Actual Behavior

```
Error code: Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/CreateVm/ConfigureNetworking/0x803b0001
The network was not found.
```

#### Diagnostic Logs

*No response*

**How to resolve this?**

related to https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10089#issue-1704237526

Comment: Looking at the error code, the results for it and your GitHub issue comments, you likely enabled HyperV in Windows and didn't restart the system, even though it told you to do that.

Comment: what does ITNOA means?

Answer (score 8):

If I encounter the error message *Wsl/Service/CreateInstance/CreateVm/ConfigureNetworking/0x...* on the screen when starting [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux), I usually resolve it by restarting the **wslservice**. To do this, I open an elevated command prompt and execute the following commands:

```
net stop wslservice
net start wslservice
```

These commands stop and start the **wslservice**, which often resolves the problem.